# Application not installing on android emulator

Tags: android

I am developing an application in android Geocoder.When I run the applicaion its showing
[2011-01-11 11:08:13 - GeoTourProject] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'Name'
[2011-01-11 11:08:25 - GeoTourProject] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2011-01-11 11:08:25 - GeoTourProject] \GeoTourProject\bin\GeoTourProject.apk installed on device
[2011-01-11 11:08:25 - GeoTourProject] Done!

What should i do to install the application on android stimulator....??

Thanks in advance
Tushar Sahni

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to make some changes in the code (like inserting a space in the .java files in your project) so that project is recompiled & deployed.

If it still throws error 'Application already deployed' then you can uninstall application by using **adb uninstall** & then install app

Answer (score 0):

If you are not getting any errors, then probably you are already fine.
Restart the emulator just to be sure. Rebuild the project and run it.

It takes a few seconds(takes about 20 on mine) for the emulator to start ans show the app.

It may also be deployed, but tucked inside the menu. So, drag open the menu bar where you see the applications such as Alarm etc. There you should see your own application too. Just click it to open it.