# The application is not installed in phone

Tags: android

While running my android application in emulator,it shows "The application is not installed in phone".Can anyone tell why this happens?

Comment: Any detailed error info or log?

Comment: At what point does this happen? If you get a message like this during installation likely you've got your signatures mixed up. Try uninstall / re-install if so. OR make a new emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try restarting your Emulator...

check this [Application not installing on android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654612/application-not-installing-on-android-emulator)

and this [application not installing on android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229468/application-not-installing-on-android-emulator)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are trying to deploy an app from your emulator, which will be signed with the debug key, over the app on your phone that was signed with your true production release key.

I have seen this error a lot when the debug certificates signed you used to sign the different apps are not the same.